# Issue with POST Request Header and Payload Being Segmented into Two Frames

Tags: http, post, nanomsg

Problem Description:
When using the nanomsg library to send a POST request, the header and payload of the request are segmented into two frames instead of being sent as a single packet. According to the HTTP/1.1 protocol specification, a POST request should be sent as a complete entity, without being split into multiple frames.

[image]

This situation doesn't happen when i use curl to send the same message to the the uri
Is this a system problem or a feature of nanomsg?
I appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you!